# eq() vs index() jquery

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I want to access elements inside a `for` loop, which `jQuery` construct should I use?

`eq()` or `index()` and how different are they?

Comment: could you share the code for your for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were in a loop you would want to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - because .eq() returns the jQuery object at the index passed in.

```
for( i= 0; i<3; i++){
   $('div').eq(i); // <-- gets div elements from index 0-2
});
```

If you were using an .each() to loop through it already has the index,element arguments

```
              //(key,value)  <-- if map
$.each(function(indexInArray, valueOfElement){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the usage of each like this

```
.each(function(index) {
    $(this) //references the element
    index //references the index
});
```